# Xeroizer syntax error, unexpected ',' upon upgrade to 3.0.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Good day everyone. Hope somebody can help me. I am having error on a gem "Xeroizer:3.0.1" upon running any rake command. See screenshot below.

[image]

This one is from my Travis CI. I've also tried running rake commands locally but the issue persists. I've checked the ruby syntax, it's fine.

My version of Ruby is 2.0.0, Rails i s4.0.0 and rake is 11.3.0

Comment: Please post text as text rather than pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of that method uses [required keyword arguments](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments#required-keyword-arguments). Unfortunately, these were not supported before Ruby 2.1. That means you have to at least update your Ruby version to 2.1.0 to use this gem.

Comment: but according to this website, the keyword arguments is a feature that i s available in Ruby 2.0 and higher https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/ruby-keyword-arguments. but let me give it a shot. thanks!

Comment: @rjcarl Keyword arguments were introduced in Ruby 2.0 but _required_ keyword arguments were only introduced in Ruby 2.1. See the section "Required keyword arguments" on the page you posted in your comment.